Logspace computation of Zeckendorf representation
By Zeckendorf's theorem any given integer can be represented as sum of Fibonacci numbers.
Given $n\in\mathbb N_{\geq 3}$ is there a logspace algorithm to represent $n$ as sum of $O(polylog(n))$ Fibonacci numbers?
There is a greedy algorithm but I am not sure if it is in Logspace and has $O(polylog(n))$ digits.

$n$ is given in binary, I assume? Then the greedy algorithm isn't logspace, and I don't believe this can be done, but I'm not sure. Do you know is base conversion can be done in logspace?

Fibonacci numbers grow exponentially. Thus the Zeckendorf representation, or more generally any representation as a sum of Fibonacci numbers with bounded multiplicity, obviously has only $O(\log n)$ “digits”.

@CommandMaster Base conversion can be done in logspace, in fact in uniform $\mathrm{TC}^0$, and I’d expect this to be possible for Zeckendorf representation as well.

@EmilJeřábek could you give a reference for that result?

@CommandMaster As with all nontrivial results about coputability in uniform $\mathrm{TC}^0$, the ultimate reference is Hesse, Allender, and Barrington, Uniform constant-depth threshold circuits for division and iterated multiplication. (Conversion from base $b$ to binary is $\vec a\mapsto\sum_ia_ib^i$, conversion from binary to base $b$ is $x\mapsto\langle\lfloor x/b^i\rfloor\bmod b:i<\log x\rangle$, thus what you really need is that you can compute bounded sums (this is easy), powering with unary exponents, and division with remainder (these two are difficult).) ...

... For logspace computability, the results from the earlier paper of Chiu, Davida, and Litow suffice (but the HAB algorithm is more elegant anyway).

And the result that uniform $\textbf{TC}^0$ is in $L$ is a consequence of Barrington's theorem, right?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Uniform $\mathrm{TC}^0$ is in L more or less trivially from the definition.

Conversion from binary to the Zeckendorf representation can be done in uniform $\def\tc{\mathrm{TC}^0}\tc$, and a fortiori in logspace.
To fix notation, the Zeckendorf representation of a natural number $N$ is
$$N=\sum_{i\ge0}a_iF_{i+2},$$
where $a_i\in\{0,1\}$, $F_n$ is $n$th Fibonacci number, and no two consecutive $a_i$ are $1$. (This is really a finite sum with $O(\log N)$ terms by the exponential growth of Fibonacci numbers.)
Using standard methods (see in particular Hesse, Allender, Barrington, Uniform constant-depth threshold circuits for division and iterated multiplication), we can compute in $\tc$ approximations of $\sqrt5$ and $\let\fii\varphi\fii=(1+\sqrt5)/2$ to any given precision, approximations of $\fii^n$ for $n$ given in unary, $F_n=\lfloor\fii^n/\sqrt5\rceil$ (where $\lfloor x\rceil=\lfloor x+1/2\rfloor$; we only need an approximation of $\phi^n/\sqrt5$ up to constant additive error here), and things like $\lfloor N\fii^{-1}\rfloor$. (For the latter, we can compute an approximation of $N\fii^{-1}$ to any given precision by the above; since it is a quadratic algebraic number, it has irrationality measure $2$, hence if we compute it to $\log_2N+O(1)$ bits of precision after the binary point, we will know that the integer part of the result is exact.)
Let
$$N\let\down\downarrow\down k=\sum_{i\ge0}a_{k+i}F_{i+2},$$
i.e., the number whose Zeckendorf representation is obtained from the one of $N$ by removing the $k$ least significant “digits”. Since the $k$th Zeckendorf digit of $N$ is the $0$th digit of $N\down k$, we are done if we can compute in $\tc$ $N\down k$ and the last digit.
Since $F_n\sim\fii^n/\sqrt5$, we expect $N\down k$ to be roughly $N\fii^{-k}$. Let us bound the difference. Using the expression $F_i=(\fii^i-(-\fii)^{-i})/\sqrt5$, it is easy to show
$$F_{k+i}=F_i\fii^k+F_k(-\fii)^{-i},$$
thus
$$\begin{align*}
N\fii^{-k}-N\down k&=\fii^{-k}\sum_{i<k}a_iF_{i+2}+\sum_{i\ge0}a_{k+i}(F_{k+i+2}\fii^{-k}-F_{i+2})\\
&=\underbrace{\fii^{-k}\sum_{i<k}a_iF_{i+2}}_A+\underbrace{F_k\fii^{-k}\sum_{i\ge0}a_{k+i}(-\fii)^{-i-2}}_B.
\end{align*}$$
Since $\sum_{i<k}a_iF_{i+2}$ is the Zeckendorf representation of an integer smaller than the first one whose digit $k$ is $1$, which is $F_{k+2}$, we have
$$0\le A\le(F_{k+2}-1)\fii^{-k}<\fii^2/\sqrt5;$$
more precisely,
$$\begin{align*}
a_{k-1}=0&\implies&0&\le A\le(F_{k+1}-1)\fii^{-k}<\fii/\sqrt5\approx0{.}7236,\\a_{k-1}=1&\implies&\fii/\sqrt5\sim F_{k+1}\fii^{-k}&\le A\le(F_{k+2}-1)\fii^{-k}<\fii^2/\sqrt5\approx1{.}1708.
\end{align*}$$
Also,
$$\begin{align*}
B&>-F_k\fii^{-k}(\fii^{-3}+\fii^{-5}+\cdots)=-F_k\fii^{-k-2}\sim-\fii^{-2}/\sqrt5\\
B&<F_k\fii^{-k}(\fii^{-2}+\fii^{-4}+\cdots)=F_k\fii^{-k-1}\sim\fii^{-1}/\sqrt5,
\end{align*}$$
where all the $\sim$ asymptotics hold in the limit $k\to\infty$. More precisely,
$$\begin{align*}
a_k=0&\implies B>-F_k\fii^{-k}(\fii^{-3}+\fii^{-5}+\cdots)=-F_k\fii^{-k-2}\sim-\fii^{-2}/\sqrt5\approx-0{.}1708,\\
a_k=0&\implies B<F_k\fii^{-k}(\fii^{-4}+\fii^{-6}+\cdots)=F_k\fii^{-k-3}\sim\fii^{-3}/\sqrt5\approx0{.}1056,\\
a_k=1&\implies B>F_k\fii^{-k}(\fii^{-2}-\fii^{-5}-\fii^{-7}-\cdots)=F_k\fii^{-k-3}\sim\fii^{-3}/\sqrt5\approx0{.}1056,\\
a_k=1&\implies B<F_k\fii^{-k}(\fii^{-2}+\fii^{-4}+\cdots)=F_k\fii^{-k-1}\sim\fii^{-1}/\sqrt5\approx0{.}2764.
\end{align*}$$
We can draw the following consequences:

We can compute $N\down1$ and $a_0$ in $\tc$. Indeed, for $k=1$, we obtain (using $a_0=1\implies a_1=0$)
$$\begin{align*}
a_0=0&\implies&-\fii^{-3}&<N\fii^{-1}-N\down1<\fii^{-2},\\
a_0=1&\implies&\fii^{-1}-\fii^{-3}=\fii^{-2}&<N\fii^{-1}-N\down1<\fii^{-1}+\fii^{-4}=1-\fii^{-3}.
\end{align*}$$
Thus,
$$\begin{align*}
N\down1&=\lfloor N\fii^{-1}+\fii^{-3}\rfloor,\\
a_0&=1\iff\{N\fii^{-1}+\fii^{-3}\}>\fii^{-1},\\
\text{i.o.w.: }a_0&=\lfloor(N+\fii^{-2})\bmod\fii\rfloor.
\end{align*}$$

We can compute in $\tc$ two candidates for $N\down k$ that differ by $1$. Taking into account that $a_{k-1}=a_k=1$ cannot happen, the bounds on $A$ and $B$ above imply
$$\begin{align*}
N\fii^{-k}-N\down k&>-F_k\fii^{-k-2}\sim-\fii^{-2}/\sqrt5\approx-0{.}1708,\\
N\fii^{-k}-N\down k&<(F_{k+2}-1)\fii^{-k}+F_k\fii^{-k-3}\sim(\fii^2+\fii^{-3})/\sqrt5\approx1{.}2764.
\end{align*}$$
We see that $N\down k$ is $\lfloor N\fii^{-k}\rceil$ or $\lfloor N\fii^{-k}\rceil-1$. (There is leeway in the bounds here, thus it suffices to take an approximation of $N\fii^{-k}$ up to constant additive error.)


We can compute in $\tc$ the pairs of candidates $N_k^+=\lfloor N\fii^{-k}\rceil$ and $N_k^-=N_k^+-1$ for all $k\le\lceil\log_\fii N\rceil$ in parallel. We can then select which candidates are correct using suitable consistency checks as follows.
Since the ${}\down1$ operation is nondecreasing and nonexpanding, we have $N_k^+\down1=N_k^-\down1$ or $N_k^+\down1=(N_k^-\down1)+1$. In view of the fact that $N\down k\in\{N_k^+,N_k^-\}$ and $N\down(k+1)\in\{N_{k+1}^+,N_{k+1}^-\}$ satisfy $(N\down k)\down1=N\down(k+1)$, one of the following cases must happen for each $k$:

$N_k^+\down1=N_{k+1}^-$. Then also $N_k^-\down1\le N_{k+1}^-$, hence the only possibility is $N\down(k+1)=N_{k+1}^-$. We indicate this by an auxiliary variable $c_{k+1}=-1$.

$N_k^-\down1=N_{k+1}^+$. Then $N\down(k+1)=N_{k+1}^+$, and we put $c_{k+1}=+1$.

$N_k^+\down1=N_{k+1}^+$ and $N_k^-\down1=N_{k+1}^-$. We put $c_{k+1}=0$.


We also have $N\down0=N=N_0^+$, hence we put $c_0=+1$. Again, we can compute all the $c_k$ in parallel in $\tc$. Now we can compute $N\down k$ in $\tc$ by
$$N\down k=\begin{cases}N_k^+,&\text{if }\exists i\le k\:c_i=+1,c_{i+1}=\dots=c_k=0,\\
N_k^-,&\text{if }\exists i\le k\:c_i=-1,c_{i+1}=\dots=c_k=0.
\end{cases}$$
(Exactly one of these two cases happens. If $i=k$, we of course interpret “$c_{i+1}=\dots=c_k=0$” as vacuously true.)
Finally, we extract $a_k=\lfloor((N\down k)+\fii^{-2})\bmod\fii\rfloor$ using the expression for $a_0$ above.

What does approximation exponent mean?

I changed it to the more common term “irrationality measure”.
